# Can i use Holo Theme with Custom title bar

Tags: android, android-theme, custom-titlebar

I am using custom title bar and its shows content as Theme.light. I tried to change it Theme.Holo but it doesn't work. can anyone help me?

```
 <resources>
<style name="CustomWindowTitleBackground" >
    <item name="android:background">#DDDDDD</item>
</style>

<style name="CustomTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo">
    <item name="android:windowTitleSize">73dip</item>
    <item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowTitleBackgroundStyle">@style/CustomWindowTitleBackground</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Provide some more details. Are you using the support action bar? When using the app compat action bar (from the support library) you can only use Theme.AppCompat / Theme.AppCompat.Light and related ones for your activity.